# How does the shader know that I'm editing color and not something else

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

There's this fragment shader which does work, but I do not understand its logic:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

// the input variable from the vertex shader (same name and same type)  
in vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vertexColor;
}
```

So how does the shader know that FragColor is supposed to represent the color of the shader, there is no assignment anywhere.

I'm saying it because in the vertex shader it's clear what is happening:

```
#version 330 core
// the position variable has attribute position 0
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

// specify a color output to the fragment shader
out vec4 vertexColor;

void main()
{
    // see how we directly give a vec3 to vec4's constructor
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    // set the output variable to a dark-red color
    vertexColor = vec4(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers

Answer (score 2):

The fragment shader does not know that `FragColor` represent a "color". For the shader it is just a vector with 4 components. The output(s) of the fragment shader are written into the frambuffer. A fragment shader has no other output (except depth buffer and stencil buffer). Therefore the shader does not need to know that the output variable represents a color.
See also [Fragment Shader - Output buffers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers).